# Matching req.http.Host in Varnish via Regex vs Standard Operators

Tags: varnish, regex

I am able to do either of the following:

Host match using standard operators:

```
if (req.http.Host == "domain1.com" || req.http.Host == "domain2.com") { ... }
```

Host match via regex:

```
if (req.http.Host ~ "^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$") { ... }
```

My question is, is option #2 bad performance-wise or security-wise? I understand that omitting the start and end regex  characters could allow someone to put a domain like `domain1.com.someotherdomain.net` potentially, but with ^ and $ that doesn't seem possible.

Any other thoughts/ideas as to how to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really think that there are any performance implications of using any of the above approaches, but I usually like to stay with the regular expression as it gives me power as well as flexibility, to match a lot of things.

Regarding the security, what you said is absolutely right and using the first option can be abused.

If I would have been working on something like this, I will surely prefer the second approach.